# Is there any open-sourced alternative for build.phonegap.com?

Tags: android, ios, compiler-construction, cordova, build

i'm looking for a tool that i can install on my server and members of my team can upload code to that server and build that. In short, it should be similar to build.phonegap.com (but not necessary phonegap specific), but i can run the tool on my own server. It would be great when the tool is open-source.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial answer that may or may not help:

The code for http://www.applaudcloud.com is opened sourced at [github link](https://github.com/paulb777/AppLaudCloud).

It is still Android only and I haven't yet published good build instructions.

I'm interested in collaboration and contribution to make it better.